# can`t connect via TLS to mosquitto broker in Docker via Python

Tags: python, docker, openssl, mosquitto

I can connect unencrypted to an eclipse mosquitto broker, but I can`t connect to it via TLS. I literaly have no clue and spent hours figuring it out. If any more information is necessary let me know, please. Also if I have to change the formatting etc. of the question. If someone could tell me what to improve, what else to do to fix the issue, this would be awesome.

Where is a good source to look up the SSLError(s) as stated by Python? I suppose it is nothing mosquitto specific.

Python code that does not work:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as paho 
import time 
           
client = paho.Client() 
any_var = input() #here I connect this container to the docker network

client.tls_set("/app/certs/ca.crt")
client.tls_insecure_set(True) 
client.connect("nebula_mosquitto_container",8883,60) 
time.sleep(5)
client.publish("home/temp", "yolo")
```

here the error message from the console, where I start the docker container build from Python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/app.py", line 9, in <module>
    client.connect("nebula_mosquitto_container",8883,60)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 914, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1073, in reconnect
    sock.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1341, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_ILLEGAL_PARAMETER] sslv3 alert illegal parameter (_ssl.c:997)
```

here is the error message from Mosquitto broker log

```
nebula_mosquitto_container | 1639392719: mosquitto version 2.0.14 starting
nebula_mosquitto_container | 1639392719: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.
nebula_mosquitto_container | 1639392719: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
nebula_mosquitto_container | 1639392719: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
nebula_mosquitto_container | 1639392719: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
nebula_mosquitto_container | 1639392719: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
nebula_mosquitto_container | 1639392719: mosquitto version 2.0.14 running
nebula_mosquitto_container | 1639392770: New connection from 172.21.0.3:54511 on port 8883.
nebula_mosquitto_container | 1639392770: OpenSSL Error[0]: error:1404A417:SSL routines:ST_ACCEPT:sslv3 alert illegal parameter
nebula_mosquitto_container | 1639392770: Client <unknown> disconnected: Protocol error.
```

here is the Dockerfile of the app

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:3.10.0-alpine3.15

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer      to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

here is the .yaml file of the mosquitto broker
version: '3.5'

```
services:
  mosquitto:
    container_name: nebula_mosquitto_container
    #image: eclipse-mosquitto:2.0.14
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    hostname: nebula_mosquitto_container
    volumes:
      - ./config:/mosquitto/config/ #this mounts the config folder with the config file to     the Docker image
      - ./certs:/mosquitto/certs/ #this mounte the cert folder with certs to the Docker     image
    ports:
      - '1883:1883' #port 1883 reachable from externally for troubleshooting from WIndoiws     with mosquitto_sub.exe
      - '8883:8883' #same as above, in TLS
    networks:
      - default #a network is spun up, when starting mosquitto, where the nodes can connect     to
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  default:
```

and here the config file of the mosquitto docker broker

```
#MQTT - note: Allow anyonymous = true is weak, since the password is sent in clear and can be easily sniffed and replayed
allow_anonymous true
listener 1883

#MQTTS - note: although allow_anyonymous the whole thing is TLS authenticated & encrypted
allow_anonymous true
listener 8883
cafile /mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
certfile /mosquitto/certs/broker.crt
keyfile /mosquitto/certs/broker.key
    


# logging all and stdout means log everything to console, which is very good for troubleshooting and testing
log_type all
log_dest stdout
```

Comment: What do the mosquitto logs show for the other side of the connection? (also you only need one `allow_anonymous true` unless you use `per_listener_settings true`

Comment: Also have you double checked that the `COPY` command in the Dockerfile has copied over the `certs` directory into the container? I always have to check when copying directories.

Comment: @hardillb thank you kindly for looking at my issue! I added the mosquitto log as suggested to the question & removed one `allow_anonymous true` and I checked, if certs are in the mosquitto container (they are), but still the issue persists. Any other thoughts? Where can I get more info on the error codes "_ssl.c:997" or "1404A417:SSL" google seem to fail me here. Do yu have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because domain names cannot have underscores in them.
Learned the hard way, figured it out when using openssl s_client with -servername flag and deleted until there were no underscores left.
Protip: Use - in docker service names.

Comment: You are a savior, i wasted 2 days just to find this, its ridiculous how silly the solution was.